# How can I re-order/re-sort elements in isotope to fill in gaps?

Tags: jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

How I can fix the gaps in the jsfiddle example below:

---

http://jsfiddle.net/3443Y/1/

Comment: You can "fix" your layout concept to a certain extent by 1. making sure to use elements that aren't too wide, effectively "blocking" many columns and then 2. using the shuffle option to randomise the layout. On each reLayout, the viewer of your layout might see gap-less arrangements quite often, but not always. If you are sorting the elements in a certain order, then there will be no solution for variable sizes. See http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/elements-complete.html with variable sizes toggled and shuffle applied a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

Masonry and Isotope is to maximize number of bricks in a column and not to minimize gaps at the bottom or top or in the middle. You can only change the order of your bricks or add another column, i.e. change the width of the surrounding container. It's a np problem for filling shelves with books for example and a fast algorithm for a good solution is a 1d bin-packing or a kd-tree. Look a good description for a kd-tree is here: http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/lightmaps/default.html.